# Is using the -L flag and a addprocs script the more powerful version of -p and --machinefile?

Tags: julia, distributed-computing, compiler-flags

So I have a moderately complex set of requirements for my worker processes.
I want to use a the master slave topology, and a nondefault working directory.
I also want to mix both local and remote workers.

As far as I can tell from readying the `--machine-file`  section of the [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/getting-started/).
It will not let me do that.

So I am looking at the `-L <file` parameter

> >julia -h 
>   ...
>    -L, --load          Load  immediately on all processors 
>   ...

So if I do not use the `-p` or --machine-file` flags, then there is initially only one processer so the *all processors* just mean on the only processor.

So I tried this out

#### start_workers.jl

```
addprocs([
          ("cluster_c4_1",:auto),
          ("cluster_c4_2",:auto)
    ],
        dir="/mnt/",
        topology=:master_slave
        )

addprocs(
        dir="/mnt/",
        topology=:master_slave
        )
```

#### test.jl

```
println("*************")
println(workers())
println("-------------")
```

#### Running it:

```
>julia -L start_workers.jl pl.jl 
*************
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]
-------------
```

So it looks all good, got my 20 workers.
Have I done anything unreasonable? Is this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly how I'm deploying it on a HPC cluster under Torque scheduler. In fact I'm in the process of re-writing the the cluster manager to support more options when adding processes through the Torque scheduling systems in particular, so I've spent quite a bit of time looking into this.

You might also want to be aware there are various ClusterManagers, `Pkg.add("ClusterManagers")` that extend the ability of addprocs under a variety of environments, such as when you need to request the resources from a scheduler. It looks like passwordless ssh is possible for you, so the default cluster manager is sufficient in your case.

I don't believe there is any way of defining the extra topology and directory parameters on the command line, so your approach is correct.