# Julia equivalent of Python multiprocessing.Pool.map

Tags: multiprocessing, julia

My multi processing needs are very simple: I work in machine learning, and I sometimes need to evaluate an algorithm in multiple datasets, or multiple algorithms in a dataset, or some such. I just need to run a function with some arguments and get a number.

I need no RPC, shared data, nothing.

In Julia, I am getting an error with the following code:

```
type Model
    param
end

# 1. I have several algorithms/models
models = [Model(i) for i in 1:50]

# 2. I have one dataset
X = rand(50, 5)

# 3. I want to paralelize this function
@everywhere function transform(m)
    sum(X .* m.param)
end

addprocs(3)
println(pmap(transform, models))
```

I keep getting errors such as,

```
ERROR: LoadError: On worker 2:
UndefVarError: #transform not defined
```

Also, is there a way to avoid having to place `@everywhere` everywhere? Can I just tell that all variables should be copied over to the workers when they are created (as is done in Python `multiprocessing`)?

My typical code looks obviously much more complicated than this, with models ranging several files.

For reference, this is what I would do in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import time

# 1. I have several algorithms/models
class Model:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param
models = [Model(i) for i in range(1,51)]

# 2. I have one dataset
X = np.random.random((50, 5))

# 3. I want to paralelize this function
def transform(m):
    return np.sum(X * m.param)

import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
print(pool.map(transform, models))
```

Answer (score 4):

Core issues is you need to add the processes *before* you attempt to define things on them.
`addprocs` should always be the first thing you do, before `using` even (see below).
This is why it is often done with the `-p` flag when you start julia.
Or with a `---machinefile <file>` or [with a `-L <file>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250274/is-using-the-l-flag-and-a-addprocs-script-the-more-powerful-version-of-p-and)

`@everywhere` exectutes the code on all processes the currently exist.
i.e. process added after the @everywhere do not have the code executed on them.

Also you missed a few @everywheres.

```
addprocs(3)

@everywhere type Model
    param
end

# 1. I have several algorithms/models
models = [Model(i) for i in 1:50]

# 2. I have one dataset
@everywhere X = rand(50, 5)

# 3. I want to paralelize this function
@everywhere function transform(m)
    sum(X .* m.param)
end

println(pmap(transform, models))
```

---

### Alternatives with fewer `@everywhere`s.

#### use a block to send a whole block of code `@everywhere`

```
addprocs(3)
@everywhere begin
    type Model
        param
    end

    X = rand(50, 5)

    function transform(m)
        sum(X .* m.param)
    end
end

models = [Model(i) for i in 1:50]

println(pmap(transform, models))
```

### Use local variables

Local variables (including functions), are sent as required.
though this doesn't help for types.

```
addprocs(3)

@everywhere type Model
    param
end

function main() 
    X = rand(50, 5)

    models = [Model(i) for i in 1:50]

    function transform(m)
        sum(X .* m.param)
    end

    println(pmap(transform, models))
end

main()
```

#### Use modules

When you `using Foo` the module `Foo` is loaded on all processes.
But not brought into scope.
It is a bit weird and counter intuitive.
So much so that I can't conjure a working example of it.
but someone else might.

Comment: Won't `@everywhere X = rand(50, 5)` produce a unique dataset on each process?

Comment: This answer was more than I was bargaining for. Thank you! My confusion was thinking that `addprocs()` would use `fork()`, which shallow-copies the memory state to the child process. For the simple stuff I do the simple POSIX paradigm works great. I will try to change my code to Julia's approach and get back to you.

Comment: @rickhg12hs from my testing, you are correct. This isn't a big problem for me because my datasets are not generated stochastically. At the same time, they take time to load... I guess I will either want to use a `SharedArray` or use the "local variables" approach, which I dislike because for the kind of work I do, scripts/global variables work best.

Comment: I have decided to go with the local variables approach, and added a `X = SharedArray(X)` because I think this will avoid having the array copied over to every child thread... Can you guys confirm this is a good idea? (I did some benchmarking and it seems to improve very slightly, but it's inconclusive.)

Comment: @rickhg12hs good point. 
@Ricardo I've never managed to get `SharedArray` working in a way that pleased me. (I think that that is more a property of the types of problems i work on, than an issue with `SharedArray)`) so I'm not good to answer that.
also: (non-const) Global variables cause bad performance every time they are used in julia, because they always cause type-instability.