# How to implement multiprocessing within the same module in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am attempting to run function testcase() within function wrapper() while using multiprocessing to call function testcase() multiple times. I want to save the result of the function call to testcase() and append it to an array for future use, but I am receiving the following error:

```
julia> tester.wrapper()
ERROR: UndefVarError: testcase not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] wrapper() at playground.jl:21
 [2] top-level scope at none:0
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741667/julia-equivalent-of-python-multiprocessing-pool-map) post, I have tried to add the @everywhere macro to the module, and I wrapped the testcase() function with @everywhere. Furthermore, I have wrapped the testcase() function with a begin block with @everywhere. I have also tried to wrap the wrapper() function with @everywhere, but that results in `wrapper not defined`.

This is an oversimplified version of the code I am using:

```
# Ran addprocs(2) from REPL

@everywhere module tester
using Distributed

# Some function that returns a value
@everywhere begin
    function testcase(num)
        return sqrt(num)
    end # function
end # begin

# Another function that uses multiprocessing
function wrapper()
    # Store all results of testcase() in the results array
    results = []

    for i in range(1, 100; step=3)
        # Utilize 3 processes
        for j = 1:3
            push!(results, remotecall_fetch(testcase, j, i+(j-1)))
        end # for
    end # for

    return results
end # function
end # module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to wrap the function `testcase` in a `@everywhere` since the module is already `@everywhere`:

```
   @everywhere module tester
   using Distributed

   function testcase(num)
           return sqrt(num)
   end # function

   function wrapper()
       results = []

       for i in range(1, 100; step=3)
           # Utilize 3 processes
           for j = 1:3
               push!(results, remotecall_fetch(testcase, j, i+(j-1)))
           end # for
       end # for

       return results
   end # function
   end
```

`tester.wrapper()` returns as expected:

```
102-element Array{Any,1}:
  1.0
  1.4142135623730951
  1.7320508075688772
  2.0
  2.23606797749979
  [...]
```

But, you code still does not run in parallel because you call `testcase` and wait for the result before proceeding.
The function `pmap` (or a `@distributed for` with a `SharedArray`) might be a better option here:

```
   @everywhere module tester
   using Distributed

   # Some function that returns a value
   function testcase(num)
           return sqrt(num)
   end # function

   # Another function that uses multiprocessing
   wrapper() = pmap(tester.testcase,1:102)
   end
```

You get the same answer as before as the code runs in parallel.

Note that threads in Julia also be an option if you are working with a single computer (but multiple cores).

Comment: Cool! This works, and `pmap` looks interesting, but in Julia, do threads leverage the use of multiple cores as needed or are they restricted to one core?

Comment: yes, basically: threads: N cores on 1 machine; multi-processing (or distributed):  N cores on M machines (where M can be 1 or more);

Comment: Off topic, but is it possible to control the number of active threads within the Julia program? Running `export JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4` only works in the terminal and `run(\`export JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4\`)` fails.